# Does amide ion prefers to act as a base than a nucleophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

In this question, I think that amide ion, being a good nucleophile should attack on the terminal carbon through  $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism to form compound (c), but the answer given is (b), and the solution:
[image]

But I am not able to understand the kinetic factors that favour the amide ion to act as a base rather than a nucleophile. I think it is much easier for a strongly nucleophilic amide ion to act as a nucleophile through a one step $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction (polar aprotic solvent will also favour it), rather than first acting as a base and then the carbanion acting as a nuceophile. The $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond is polar, which also increases the chances of an $\mathrm{S_N2}$, but the $\ce{C-H}$ bond is not that polar.
So, my question is, will (b) be the major product, and if yes, than what are the kinetic factor that favour it in comparison to (c)?

(Note: The reaction is assumed to be under kinetic control.)

Comment: Your mistake here is to think of amide anion as strongly nucleophilic. It is a very strong base and the protons next to the sulfonyl group have a pKa ~30. It is also poorly soluble in DME

Comment: Please note that it's written $\mathrm{S_N2}$ `$\mathrm{S_N2}`, not $\ce{SN^2}$ `$\ce{SN^2}` (the latter means *sulfur and nitrogen squared*).

Comment: In general, acid base reactions are very fast. See https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/05/21/acid-base-reactions-are-fast/

Comment: I second what @mcole said. In general, acid-base reactions are faster than nucleophilic substitution. Which is also the reason why Grignard reagent cannot be used for nucleophilic addition on aldehydes/ketones which have acidic hydrogen like $\ce{-OH}$, $\ce{-COOH}$ and so on.

Comment: After acid base reaction has occured, the substitution by carbanion will be faster than amide ion since intramolecular substitution is faster because of greater chances of attack. Am I right?